# Differencing the instruction of the same opcode

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code

I am coding a ftrace program on Linux(64 bits) for study purpose, and I need to parse the instruction using ptrace() syscall.

The instruction I am interested in are ret and call. The call instruction may take different opcodes (0xe8, 0x9a and 0xff). This is the last one that questions me: this 0xff can also stand for inc, dec, jmp and push instruction, but I read that the "register / opcode field" changes.

My question is: How can I have the information that call is called and not dec or inc? I have access to the opcodes and the registers.

Thank you for reading and helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell the difference by looking at 3-bit field (bits 5,4,3) in the next instruction byte.

```
000     inc instruction

001     dec instruction

010     intra-segment indirect call

011     inter-segment indirect call

100     intra-segment indirect jump

101     inter-segment indirect jump

110     push instruction

111     unused
```

Comment: so if the next instruction byte is 0001 1000, the bits (5,4,3) would be 110 meaning we deal with a push instruction?
I would have another question if anyone knows the answer: Why is there not the same number of call and ret in an executable, parsing the call (0xff / 0xe8 / 0x9a) and the ret (0xc3, 0xc2, 0xca, 0xcb) opcodes? Is the mistake from me or do I lack an information?

Comment: If the next instruction byte is `0001 1000`, the bits (5,4,3) would be `011.`

Comment: Your commented question: if there are 3 calls to one function, the code (might) contain 3 calls and 2 rets - one from the function and one from the main - or not. `main` might end with a system call.

Comment: In my test I got 777 calls for 751 return (and the binary I test on does exit with a return on the main). I find these results very high for a 2 functions and 10 lines binary... I know the libc is loaded before the executable begins but still.

Comment: I can't really say since you are asking a different question. In 8086 the instructions are of variable length, so it's no use just looking for `0xFF` bytes, you need to completely disassemble to find the first byte of each sequence of instruction bytes.

Comment: you mean that the information leads before the 0xff and when I got the opcode along with the parameters, the information aren't in what I read?

Comment: I am saying you aren't being clear. Please ask a new question with sample codes etc.

Comment: He's saying there could be a `0xFF` in the middle of another instruction, so you can't scan an insn stream for just that.  But if you're using `ptrace` in a way that single-steps and takes care of stopping at insn boundaries for you, then this method should work.  You didn't say how your test works in enough detail for us to say if those numbers are right for libc startup.  I'd believe it though; modern glibc and shared libs do a TON of stuff at startup.  A lot of the call/ret pairs might be very small functions.